# Hash maps in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Given:

```
hash = { "value" => 4, "details" => "I am some details"}, {"value" => 5, "details" => "I am new details"}
```

can I do something like:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
   puts "#{key} is #{value}"
end
```

to get something like:

```
{ "value" => 4, "details" => "I am some details"} is {"value" => 5, "details" => "I am new details"} is
```

If a hash table (map) is not what I want to do this with, what would be? Databases are out of the question. The user should be able to continue to add on to the end with another `{}` if they need to filling out the same details as what's in the first two.

Comment: Don't tell us something "like" the output you got, tell us the actual output.  Copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

You've created an array of hashes, which you can do more explicitly as:

```
hashes = [{:value => "foo"}, {:value => "bar"}]
```

You can then append with

```
hashes << {:value => "baz"}
```

If you're ever wondering what type of variable you're working with, you can do `var.class`:

```
hash = { "value" => 4, "details" => "I am some details"}, {"value" => 5, "details" => "I am new details"}
hash.class #=> Array
```

Answer (score 1):

A [Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) is a mapping of *Distinct* Keys to Values; there are Map *variations* which relax this, but Ruby's Hashmap follows the standard Map ADT.

In this case an Array of two different Hashes (each with a "value" and a "details") is being created.

```
>  x = [1,2] # standard Array literal
   => [1,2]   
>  x = 1,2   # as in the posted code, no []'s, but ..
   => [1,2]  # .. the same: the =, production created the Array here!
```

So it's not a Hash in `hash`, but rather an Array (containing two Hash elements) :)

Compare the results with the following and note that `b` is `nil` each time:

```
["one","two","three","four"].each do |a,b|
    puts ">" + a + "|" + b
end
```

This is why it prints "hash1.to_str *is* hash2.to_str *is*" as the `each` iterates over the Array, as discussed above and only the first argument is populated with a meaningful value - one of the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what "databases are out of the question" means in this context. Sounds like you're creating a data store, and so far it looks like you have a numeric ID with a related value.

A hash is a hash; you'd add values to the hash:

```
h = { "4" => "foo" } # Initial values
h["5"] = "ohai"
h["6"] = "kthxbai"
```

Comment: no this wont work, I need to do something similar to what I am doing above where I can repeat "value" but assign different values to it.

Comment: @TheWebs Then you don't want a hash map--who knows what you want, w/o more information. A hash with an array as the value? An array of hashes? If you can't tell us precisely what you actually need, it's going to be tough to help.